# Cannot take a photo programmatically on Android 11 - intent returns canceled status

Tags: java, android, android-11

Starting an intent:

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
  CurrentFile = new File(getTempFileString());
  CurrentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", CurrentFile);
  intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, CurrentUri);
  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
  startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

Used to work. It no longer does. My method that starts after the intent is:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
}
```

The `resultCode` used to be `RESULT_OK` but is now `RESULT_CANCELED`.

If I stop checking the resultCode and just go past this, I find that the photo doesn't exist.

Based on CommonsWare's comment I extracted the logs. Of the 654 lines generated during this operation, four seem relevant.

```
2020-10-12 11:03:04.301 1471-1763/? E/MediaProvider: Creating a non-default top level directory or deleting an existing one is not allowed!
2020-10-12 11:03:04.310 477-2112/? I/AppsFilter: interaction: PackageSetting{240e1c6 com.[my app package]/10151} -> PackageSetting{193734c com.android.camera2/10124} BLOCKED
2020-10-12 11:03:04.553 390-9884/? W/ServiceManager: Permission failure: android.permission.SYSTEM_CAMERA from uid=10124 pid=11746
2020-10-12 11:03:14.097 11746-11746/? E/CAM_StateSavePic: exception while saving result to URI: Optional.of(content://[my app package].provider/external_files/[The SD card path I asked for]/1602518584301.jpg)
```

I am asking the file to get saved here:

```
new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), getString(a.getApplicationInfo().labelRes))
```

This seems to be the issue.

Comment: Check Logcat to see if the camera app that happens to be your default is logging any messages of relevance around the time that you invoke this `Intent`.

Comment: Thank you, that does lead somewhere. I updated the question and I have a little more to go on now.

Comment: You are not going to be able to write to the root of external storage next year, once your `targetSdkVersion` reaches 30. I *strongly* recommend that you write this image somewhere else -- your app should be able to contribute to `Pictures/`, for example. If you absolutely must write here in the short term, you will need to add `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` in the `<application>` element of the manifest.

Comment: Wow, I owe you a beer. I would have never found this. Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

Truly @CommonsWare deserves the credit here. The issue was the `getTempFileString()` call in the source code. I was attempting to save the file to a temp path so I could delete it right after. The file only exists shortly. Google blocked access to this. The `Camera` application received an error about not being able to save to this path, however it did not throw an error or display a message. It just returned a result of `RESULT_CANCELED` back to my application. I fixed this by updating the path used to the local cache directory `getExternalCacheDir()` and am using a sub directory inside that.

**Edit:** Adding the code that worked for me. Removed app specific text, and the error handling to keep it short and simple.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "My Application Directory");

if (!path.exists()) {
   path.mkdir();
}

File imageFile = File.createTempFile("Your file Name", ".jpg", path);

Context context = getActivity().getBaseContext();
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", imageFile);

intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

List<ResolveInfo> resInfoList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfoList) {
   String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
   context.grantUriPermission(packageName, CurrentUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
}

startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_CAPTURE); // IMAGE_CAPTURE = 0
```

Comment: "I was attempting to save the file to a temp path so I could delete it right after" -- you might consider using `getCacheDir()`. `FileProvider` supports it and there are no permissions issues. Regardless, I'm glad that you got it working!

Comment: Did you get getExternalCacheDir() to work? I get a resultcode of 0 back from the camera intent and when I look at logcat I see an access denied (Andriod 11 emulator)

Comment: @Rob I updated my answer with some source code

Comment: I had some problems so I went back to the Android docs and it now seems happy using getExternalFilesDir provided I do everything given in https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics#java

Answer (score 1):

you shouldn't use "getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()" because this is SHARED STORAGE behaviour and from (probably) 5 july 2021 all applications on the Play Store MUST target android SDK 30 and use Scoped Storage only (so you can't use "requestLegacyStorage", idk about "preserveLegacyStorage").

I suggest you to change the destination path  to:

```
context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getPath();
```

Have a nice Day & a Nice Coding :D

Answer (score 0):

This is a strange behaviour but if you use **MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT** flag method *onActivityResult()* will always return null data and you are expected to look for your data at location you pointed out here:

```
CurrentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", CurrentFile);
```

So there are two different ways of handling result you are looking for