# Android Camera intent not responding in Android 11

Tags: android, camera, android-11

I am working with Camera Intent. Everything is working fine till Android 10, but in Android 11 I am getting result Code 0.

1. Manifest Permission

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   ```
2. Intent function with file creation :

   ```
    private void openCameraApp()
    {
        Intent picIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE).
                addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        try {

            String file_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() +
                    "/" + mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);

            File dir = new File(file_path);
            if (!dir.exists())
                dir.mkdirs();

            imagePath = new File(dir, mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name) + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                picIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, FileProvider.getUriForFile(mContext, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, imagePath));
                setUri(FileProvider.getUriForFile(mContext, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, imagePath));
            } else {
                picIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(imagePath));
                setUri(Uri.fromFile(imagePath));
            }

            ((Activity) mContext).startActivityForResult(picIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.e(e);
        }
    }
   ```

I have added `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` in application tag of manifest file.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

See [intent.resolveActivity returns null in API 30](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62535856/intent-resolveactivity-returns-null-in-api-30/64204646). Maybe there is something wrong with AndroidManifest.

```
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

Or see [Cannot take a photo programmatically on Android 11 - intent returns canceled status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64321017/cannot-take-a-photo-programmatically-on-android-11-intent-returns-canceled-sta).

Comment: Thanks for the help and sorry for being too late. I have already tried this but this is showing error while I am using <queries> in manifest, even I have used higher sdk level in my gradle.

Comment: @developer, sorry, I didn't understand, what error has it shown? Maybe a warning? And after that it didn't compile or didn't work?

Comment: See the error :  Element queries is not allowed here 
 Inspection info: This inspection highlights unallowed XML tags in Android resource files and AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: @developer, it's just a warning. The `<queries>` tag even exists in https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/package-visibility. You can suppress warnings.

Comment: Thank you. I wonder why Android does not make a public announcement on such changes.

Comment: @ekashking, thanks! Agree with you, Android 11 brought many security changes, especially in storage handling, and often we knew about them, when something was broken.

Comment: I have added the same code not working.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71953359/camera-intent-not-working-proper-in-android-11-here-is-below-my-code-i-receive

Comment: @Siddharthkheni, but in your code you don't have `<queries>`.

Comment: @CoolMind I have added. didn't work it.

    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
        </intent>

        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent>
  </queries>

Comment: Those who new to this, don't forgot to add this queries outside the application tag in manifest.

Answer (score 1):

Remove this .putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT

Answer (score 0):

The result code in activity.java indicates the camera activity has been cancelled:

```
/** Standard activity result: operation canceled. */
public static final int RESULT_CANCELED    = 0;
/** Standard activity result: operation succeeded. */
public static final int RESULT_OK           = -1;
/** Start of user-defined activity results. */
public static final int RESULT_FIRST_USER   = 1;
```

Try launching the activity for IMAGE_CAPTURE:
`startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE)`