# Camera intent not working proper in android 11. Here is below my code. I received thumbnail image. How to receive full size image?

Tags: android, camera, android-11

I am using the camera intent to allow the take picture from the camera and use this image in the android application. I have tried many solutions. Is there any proper solution or demo? which properly works in android 11.

Here is the code that I have to receive a thumbnail image.

`(1)Here is AndroidManifest.xml`

```
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
        </intent>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CHOOSER" />
        </intent>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        </intent>

    set permission  

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

  <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES"
        tools:ignore="QueryAllPackagesPermission" />

 </uses-feature>

     <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_path" />
    </provider>
```

`(2)Open camera button code (Camera intent)`

```
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {                  String destination = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS).getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "profile_" + "/image.jpg";
                    imageUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(destination));
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, Constant.REQUEST_CAMERA);
                }
```

`(3)Result receive in onActivityResult`

```
   if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == Constant.REQUEST_CAMERA) {

                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
                imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);

   }
```

Comment: You should be getting a `FileUriExposedException`. `Uri.fromFile()` has not been usable in six years. Use `FileProvider` and `getUriForFile()` to create your `Uri`, then look to see if the camera app created your requested file with the full-size image.

Comment: @CommonsWare can you please share the demo link or code.

Comment: Here is [the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics#TaskPath). I also cover this in the "Using the Camera via 3rd-Party Apps" chapter of [this free older book of mine](https://commonsware.com/Android). The code is out of date, but the key concepts should still be good. I have a more modern example in [this chapter](https://commonsware.com/R/pages/chap-other-001.html) of [this free book](https://commonsware/R), but that example is in Kotlin and is tied to a specific situation on Android 11+ devices.